# Using wildcards with sqlite database

Tags: android, sqlite

I have this query which finds a database entry but need to have the exact location and would prefer to change it to a wild card

`Cursor myCursor = db.query(TRACK_TABLE, new String[]{KEY_TRACK_ID,KEY_TRACK_LOCATION}, KEY_TRACK_LOCATION+ "=" + "'"+location+"'", null,null, null, null, null);`

I know in standard SQL I could just use `Select * from TRACK_TABLE where location LIKE '%bray%'`

I am not sure how to do this in a `query` statement really.

Comment: AFAIK LIKE statements work the same. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: Yeah i did but just realised hadn't put spaces in after the `LIKE` and so the machine thought that it was all one big string after the `LIKE`

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use a LIKE statement:

```
Cursor myCursor = db.query(TRACK_TABLE,
                           new String[] {KEY_TRACK_ID, KEY_TRACK_LOCATION},
                           KEY_TRACK_LOCATION + " LIKE ?",
                           new String[] { location },
                           null,
                           null,
                           null,
                           null);
```